# Nginx returning 404 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I decided to change my nginx sites root to a different location, outside of the nginx directory (`etc/nginx`) but now it seems to have broken something, and I think its the permissions?

Somebody told me you cannot have an nginx site outside its nginx directory but I don't think this is true, as it doesn't make much sense, but here is the logs and commands I've tried.

```
Checked my error log and it seems to be returning this:
2019/03/25 22:53:25 [crit] 2107#2107: *1 stat() "/media/developer/megasync/workspace/coding/projects/websites/codeshare/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), cli$
2019/03/25 22:55:40 [crit] 2329#2329: *1 stat() "/media/developer/megasync/workspace/coding/projects/websites/codeshare/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), cli$
```

I've tried these commands, none work.

```
sudo chown -R www-data /media/developer/megasync/workspace/coding/projects/websites
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/developer/megasync/workspace/coding/projects/websites
sudo chown -R developer:www-data /media/developer/megasync/workspace/coding/projects/websites
```

Restarting the nginx service after running each one.

404 Not Found
nginx/1.15.5 (Ubuntu)

Running `namei -om /media/developer/megasync/workspace/coding/projects/websites` returns

```
drwxr-xr-x root      root      /
 drwxr-xr-x root      root      media
 drwxr-x--- root      root      developer
 drwxrwxrwx developer developer megasync
 drwxrwxrwx developer developer workspace
 drwxrwxrwx developer developer coding
 drwxrwxrwx developer developer projects
 drwxrwxrwx developer developer websites
```

conf file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /media/developer/megasync/workspace/coding/projects/websites/codeshare.io/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name landing.io;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: which user did you configure for nginx.conf `user  nginx;` is default ?

Comment: The directory `developer` is blocking access to any directories below it. Look at the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `namei -om /media/developer/megasync/workspace/coding/projects/websites` and you'll see that the `developer` is blocking permissions to any child directorys